# Reusable slideshow in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a slideshow in jQuery and now I want to have 2 slideshows on a page how can I make my function reusable so the 2 slideshows don't conflict with each other?

Here is my Js code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var slideCount = $('.slidek ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('.slidek ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('.slidek ul li').height();
    var screenWidth = $( window ).width();

    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * screenWidth;
    $('.lists').css({ width: screenWidth});
    $('.slidek').css({ maxWidth: screenWidth, height: "auto" });
    $('.slidek ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - screenWidth });


    $('.slidek ul li:last-child').prependTo('.slidek ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('.slidek ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('.slidek ul li:last-child').prependTo('.slidek ul');
            $('.slidek ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };
    function moveRight() {
        $('.slidek ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('.slidek ul li:first-child').appendTo('.slidek ul');
            $('.slidek ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };
    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });
});
```

And this would be the HTML structure of the slideshow.

```
<div class="slidek">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="control_next"></a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="control_prev"></a>
  <ul>
    <li class="lists">
      <div class="testimonial_container">
        <img src="****.png">
        <h2>John Doe</h2>
       </div>
    </li>
    <li class="lists">
      <div class="testimonial_container">
       <img src="****.png">
       <h2>John Doe</h2>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zbqe2w93/

Comment: for instance, you could make use of the current context (`this`) within your `move` functions to locate the relevant elements within the slide layout (your slidek div encapsulates that) which the buttons are part of and control those elements only.

Comment: you could give your slideshows different IDs

Comment: @KrisJ. I could but if I will ever want to add more slideshows, I have to manually add id's but I would prefer to have a reusable function instead of that :)

Comment: Yeah that is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to investigate creating a jquery plugin pattern to make things a bit more reusable, but for sake of ease and getting started with jquery (which I am assuming you, apologies if you aren't) I will just work with what you have. There is a lot of questionable stuff in your code, but I will try and answer the question at hand without deviating into other territories and acting like a zealot.

You need to consider the jQuery context. At the moment you are targeting all the elements in the page with the same selector, so (for example) when you click the right arrow, it will change ALL of the sliders on the page.

Generally you target the parent of the container, then use that to find the elements within and bind and reference them. Also you can create references to your elements so you aren't trying to find them everytime you want to change them.

Note this is a bit of an anti pattern, but it's how I started when I was learning e.g. (just a sample)

```
$('.slidek').each(function() {

    var $container = $(this), // get the container for this iteration. The prefix is just to show it's a jquery element
        $slider = $('ul', $container), // this refers to only the ul within the container
        $rightArrow = $('a.control_prev', $container); // only the right arrow within the container

    function moveRight() {
        // do your moveRight code referencing $slider
        // also "this" used here will reference the anchor you clicked
        // this can be handy if you want to combine the left/right functions
        // because the left/right code has a very similar structure
        $slider.animate......
    }

    $rightArrow.click(moveRight); // attach event to only the this arrow

});
```

As I mentioned before, this isn't the best practice, but it should work for you without having to rewrite a whole bunch of code. I will try to dredge up some sample patterns that I like, or if someone could add something in the comments. I would suggest doing some reading on jQuery plugins, just be mindful that most of the stuff you read these days will probably suggest you need to install 3 flavours of grunt/gulp and use require modules etc. Just get back to the basics and learn from there.

Found this https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-patterns. It looks oldish, but then again, so is jQuery.

Comment: perfect, exactly what I was looking for, will look into patterns, if you have some good resources to share I would appreciate :)

Comment: The first link I was looking for is the one that A. Sri mentioned their answer below https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/ to get the grips of how a plugin works. Then I usually use a pattern like this one https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-patterns/blob/master/patterns/jquery.basic.plugin-boilerplate.js and then modify as you get more confident.

Comment: A couple of general considerations with plugins is that [a] you should be able to put more than one on page  (what you are addressing here) and [b] Someone using your plugin shouldn't need to access elements to get at the methods i.e. they should be able to do something like $('.slidek').slider('next') and not $('.slidek a.right').click()

Answer (score 2):

make your slideshow as a jquery plugin.

and then you will be able to use it as many time as you want.

there is simple way to create your own plugin you can refer here.

https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/